# Python Inconsistent Special Character Storage In String

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-3.7, unicode-normalization

Version is Python 3.7. I've just found out python sometimes will store the character ñ in a string with multiple representations and I'm completely at a loss as to why or how to deal with it.

I'm not sure the best way to show this issue, so I'm just going to show some code output.

I have two strings, s1 and s2 both set to equal `'Dan Peña'`

They are both of type string.

I can run the code:

```
print(s1 == s2) # prints false
print(len(s1)) # prints 8
print(len(s2)) # prints 9
print(type(s1)) # print 'str'
print(type(s2)) # print 'str'
for i in range(len(s1)):
    print(s1[i] + ", " + s2[i])
```

The output of the loop would be:

```
D, D
a, a
n, n
 ,  
P, P
e, e
ñ, n
a, ~
```

So, are there any python methods for dealing with these inconsistencies, or at least some specification as to when python will use which representation?

It would also be nice to know why Python would choose to implement this way.

Edit:

One string is being retrieved from a django database and the other string is from a string obtained from parsing a filename from a list dir call.

```
from app.models import Model
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        load_dir = "load_dir_name"
        save_dir = "save_dir"

        files = listdir(load_dir)
        save_file_map = {file[:file.index("_thumbnail.jpg")]: f"{save_dir}/{file}" for file in files}
        for obj in Model.objects.all():
            s1 = obj.title
            save_file_path = save_file_map[s1] # Key error when encountering ñ.
```

However, when I search through the `save_file_map` dict I find a key that is exactly the same as s1 except the ñ is encoded as characters `n~` rather than character `ñ`.

Note that the files I load in the above code with list dir are named base on the obj.title field in the first place, so it should be guaranteed that a file with the name is in the `load_dir` directory.

Comment: There are many different binary encodings of characters. It looks like you're comparing the binary encodings, not converting them to strings.

Comment: Show how you're setting `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: For me, s='Dan Peña' only shows len(s) = 9.

Comment: @Barmar they are both of type string I checked that. One of the strings is read from a listdir and is parsed out of a file name, and one of the strings is read from a Django database char field.

Comment: @dolgom I just print(len('Dan Peña')) and got 8 in Python 3.5. I was also able to get two different lengths for the same string in Python 3.7

Comment: The problem may have to do with how the string is encoded in the DB, you're not converting it properly when fetching it.

Comment: @Barmar: And/or it's being corrupted on insertion into the DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to normalize the strings to use the same representation. Right now, one of them is using an `n` character + a tilde character (2 chars), while the other is using a single character representing an n with a tilde.

`unicodedata.normalize` should do what you want. See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).

You'll want to call this like so: `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s1)`. `'NFC'` tells `unicodedata.normalize` that you want to use the composed forms for everything, e.g. the 1 char version of `ñ`. There are other options supplied in the docs besides `'NFC'`, which one you use is totally up to you.

Now, at what point you normalize is up to you (I don't know how you app is structured). For example you could normalize before inserting into the database, or normalize every time you read from the database.

Comment: The types are of str, not unicode data. I suppose it is possible to convert to unicode data, normalize, and then convert back, but that still leaves open the question "why do python str's have multiple representations for special characters?"

Comment: This is the answer I would have posted (if the problem was actually decomposition, but it doesn't seem to be, since an actual tilde, not a combining tilde, seems to be being printed, though that could be a difference in font support) with one minor exception: You almost always want `'NFC'` (or `'NFKC'`) not `'NFD'`. `'NFC'` gets you as close as possible to one character == one grapheme (it can't handle all cases because not all combinations of combining characters have dedicated code points to compose to).

Comment: @YungGun: You're using Python 3; the `str` type *is* the type that holds Unicode data. In Python 3, there is one and only one text type, `str`, which can hold any Unicode text; it was only in Python 2 where there was a distinction between `str` (ASCII or locale specific text, or binary data) and `unicode` (any text).

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: I'd upvote the change, but I already upvoted. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are correct. This solution works just fine.

Comment: @YungGun regarding why there's multiple ways to represent special characters like n tilde, that's a unicode thing, not a python thing. It's more or less for backwards compatibility with other encodings if i recall correctly.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Thanks its making more sense now.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: It's not just a back compat hack; combining characters allow for programmatic manipulation of text in ways that may be useful. For example, in decomposed form, you could replace all `a`s with `e`s or the like, and end up with `e` that are accented (or not) to match. In composed form, you'd have to run N rounds of replacement, one for each diacritic (accent, cedilla, tilde, etc.) that might occur. I've only ever used decomposed form to strip diacritics (converting Latin text to closest equivalent ASCII by decomposing, then stripping non-ASCII), but there are other uses.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yup, that's true. I was more referring to why we still have precomposed forms still.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso: Ah. For every other purpose I prefer precomposed simply to minimize the discrepancy between string length and grapheme count. But yeah, decomposed forms could eliminate the need for composed forms, but hey, latin-1 already existed and we built the Unicode standard on top of it, so we're never getting rid of composed characters.