# How do I correctly index Spanish language documents using Solr?

Tags: utf-8, solr

How do I correctly index Spanish language documents using Solr?

More specifically, I have tried two different "character folding" techniques to index non-ASCII characters, and neither one seem to work 100% of the time. Both techniques allow me to find some accented character but not others.

For example, I use the ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
 <analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwordsspanish.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwordsspanish.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Or I use the MappingCharFilterFactory like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
 <analyzer type="index">
  <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory"  mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwordsspanish.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
  <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory"  mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwordsspanish.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In both cases I can search for and find some words with non-ASCII characters and some not. For examnple, I can find documents with the word "presentará" but not necessarily all of them. I know my corpus includes the word "señor" but I can never find it.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the default field type `text_es` for these fields? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/language-analysis.html#spanish

Comment: Another thing to consider is to make sure the encoding is correct, for example there are two ways of encoding "ñ" and that might be why you cannot find "señor" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56760563/446681)